# JavaScript expressions, comma delimited within parentheses

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict';

(true, false, 1);
```

Do the parentheses create a single expression out of multiple constituent expressions?

I haven't seen this syntax before.

Edit: the original code that piqued interest:

```
function AddWatermark(controlName, defaultValue, cssValue) {
    document.getElementById(controlName).value == "" 
    && 
    (document.getElementById(controlName).value = defaultValue, document.getElementById(controlName).className = cssValue); //I am interested in this syntax on the RHS of the logical AND operator
}
```

Comment: What's that???? Show us more detail... just calling (true) makes no sense...

Comment: I suspect it is a minification technique

Comment: The comma is an operator.

Comment: i wonder how the expression gets evaluated.

Comment: @C-linkNepal no, there's nothing conditional in that expression

Comment: I originally posted a syntactically equivalent, but different, expression. In the source: `(document.getElementById(controlName).value = defaultValue, document.getElementById(controlName).className = cssValue);`

Comment: Don't be encouraged to write code like that, it has nothing to recommend it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In some programming languages (including c++ and js), the comma operator stands for *"Evaluate all the expressions separated by commas and return the last one"*. For example:

```
var x = (true, false, 1);
console.log(x) // 1
```

Here's another one to show you that expressions are evaluated:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var x = (i++, j--);
console.log(i, j, x) // 1 -1 0
```

The function `AddWaterMark` essentially can be rewritten as:

```
function AddWatermark(controlName, defaultValue, cssValue) {
    if (document.getElementById(controlName).value == "") { 
        document.getElementById(controlName).value = defaultValue;    
        document.getElementById(controlName).className = cssValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never figure it out, but for loops use this syntax. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator)

Answer (score 8):

*"Do the parenthesis create a single expression out of multiple constituent expressions?"*

No, it's the commas that do that.  The comma operator evaluates the expressions on both sides of it, and returns the right hand side.

Therefore:

```
e = (a = b, c = d)
```

Will perform the two inner assignments, and then assign `c` to `e`.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers explained the comma pretty well I guess, and Nikola's answer also shows you how the logical and operator `&&` is used as an alternative of an `if` statement, due to its short-circuiting evaluation.

As for the brackets - they just alter operator precedence, because the comma operator has a very low precedence naturally.

`a && b, c` would be interpreted as `(a && b), c`, i.e. `if(a)b;c`

`a && (b, c)` is `if(a){b;c}`