# How to print JavaScript array with set of pairs inside array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I was going through documentation of JavaScript about arrays and objects.I found one unique query about arrays

```
var a= [1,2,3]
console.log(a)     // give [1,2,3]


var b = [(1,2) , (3,4) , (5,6)]
console.log(b)     // gives [2,4,6]
```

I didn't understand the logic behind the same.It just ran over my mind.If we do same thing in python

```
a = [(1,2),(3,4)]
print(a)     // [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Can some one explain the same and can someone explain me how to get the same output in JavaScript like the way I got in python.How to iterate through all the elements in array in javascript

Comment: The result of the expression `(1,2)` in JavaScript is `2`. See [Grouping operator ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) and [Comma operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: In JavaScript parens don't create a datatype the same way they do in Python.

Comment: I got your point and understood your answer.  But now what about the iteration.How can i loop through all the elements inside that array in my case?Is there any way to do it

Comment: you should not use  the grouping operator `()` for such case. javascript !== python. if you code in javascript then think in javascript

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a Python programmer, but those parentheses differ in their functionality between Python and JavaScript.

I understand in Python they indicate a tuple literal. In JavaScript, <del>they merely group things</del> they say "execute each statement and return the last one." That's why you only see some items in your JS arrays.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280412/1371131

Comment: That's a much better duplicate. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

What you have encountered is the comma operator.

When there is no other context, a `,` in an expression behaves like an operator just like `+` or `=` or `/` etc.

The comma operator behaves as follows:

- evaluate the first expression
- ignore the result of the first expression
- evaluate the second expression
- return the value of the second expression

Thus the following code:

```
a = 1,2;
b = 1,2,3,4;
```

will result in `a` being assigned the value `2` and `b` assigned the value `4`.

This may seem kind of silly because we already have `;` but the comma operator is useful if you need more than one thing to happen in a single expression context. For example if you need more than one thing to happen in one of the conditions of a `for` loop you cannot use `;` because that is used to separate the conditional expressions. The comma operator comes to the rescue:

```
for (let a = 0, b = 0;   a < 10;   a++, b++) { //...
//          ^                          ^
//          |                          |____  two things happen here
//          |_______________________________  and here
```

So `(1,2)` is just another way to write `2`.

Therefore `[(1,2) , (3,4) , (5,6)]` and `[2,4,6]` is the same array.

Just like `[1+1, 2+2, 3+3]` and `[2,4,6]` is the same array.

They are just different ways to write `[2,4,6]`. The same way you cannot loop through the array and extract `1+` from `[1+1, 2+2, 3+3]` you cannot loop through the array and extract `(1,` from `[(1,2) , (3,4) , (5,6)]`.

If you really need an array of pairs you need to use an array of arrays:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Comment: I got your point and understood your answer.  But now what about the iteration.How can i loop through all the elements inside that array in my case.Is there any way to do it

Comment: You realise right that you only have an array of `[2,4,6]`? Like I said `(1,2)` is just a fancy way to write `2`. There is no data structure as `(1,2)`. So you loop like normal

Comment: If you really want an array of pairs you need to use an array of array: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`. There is no way to recover the value `1` from `(1,2)` because it is discarded thus the value of `(1,2)` is `2`